What is an undemanding person?
A dictionary says "If you describe someone as undemanding, you mean they are easy to be with and do not ask other people to do a great deal for them."
Can we use the term "an undemanding person" for "a person who is content"?
or are "an undemanding person" and "a person who is content" the same or different?
Say, I have a friend who does not posses a lot of wealth. He is happy living in his small house with few possessions. He is content. However, he is coaching a football team and he pushes his players to do a lot of hard things.
Is he undemanding?

There's no reason why a person can't be undemanding in one aspect of their life and very demanding in another. I know  guy who is very demanding about wine, but undemanding when it comes to (for example) cars.

The two adjectives are different, as demonstrated in the case of the football coach.  He is content but not undemanding.
Being content describes a
person viewing his own situation; being undemanding describes a person dealing with others.

2ADJECTIVE [verb-link ADJECTIVE] B2
If you are content, you are fairly happy or satisfied.


+1. You can also have the opposite: someone who's undemanding because they're despondent.
